# Can I start the conversation with messenger bot? (FB + BotFramework)

Tags: botframework

My bot is running fine when the user starts the conversation. But what I want to know is if I can start the conversation with the user instead user with it.

Based on the Facebook docs, I think I can do this with FB directly once I got the page scoped usedId -- e.g. through using the 'message us' plugin on our page

Now though - I use the MS botframework and wonder how to do it using that framework or if I just have to 'circumvent' the framework and do a manual POST for the initial messsage

---

K48's comment is the answer for me!

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new Activity object with the .From and .Recipient that you already know, and a random ConversationId?

Comment: Sounds hcakish but good :) ill try

Comment: @k48 thats it basically... please make it an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm answer as I did with your GitHub issue:

On Facebook messenger I resulted in using the 'Get Started Button' which you can then use to start a dialog using the postback. I also use this to gather the users information before starting a conversation with them ;).

Please see [issue #1238](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1238) on GitHub to see my answer to another query which shows you how.

Comment: I might be too dumb to get it but.. you aren't writing proactively to the user there!?

Comment: for fb, I can use the fb send API with the page-scoped userID, but how to do it with ms bf