# Is it possible to configure messenger channel without using bot framework by Microsoft?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

Might i'l get many negative votes for this. But i didn't find nothing similar.

Currently i'm using bot framework dashboard to connect my bot to Facebook by setting up Messenger channel.
All the settings, callback URLs, etc.

Is it possible to avoid bot framework dashboard by Microsoft and configure Messenger channel without those settings ?

Is it possible to configure Messenger channel directly from my bot instance without any additional tools (such bot framework dashboard) ?

Comment: No, but if you're prepared to play a bit fast and loose you can use [this api to talk directly to Messenger](https://github.com/Schmavery/facebook-chat-api).

Comment: Can you explain more about this project ? :D

Comment: I tried to clone this project, but i think this is a module or something like that.... Btw I'm using c#. Not node.js. 

Check this : http://prntscr.com/f6ljs0

Comment: It's a node.js app that acts as a bridge to the FB messenger API. It is definitely possible to use in in C# by using Edge.js to run a node script that calls the API and marshals messages back and forth. TBH you're better off with the pain of setting up channels manually!

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Can you see this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469764/how-to-turn-off-automatic-replies , please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, the configuration is currently done through the Dashboard. Out of curiosity, what's wrong with the dashboard?

Comment: There is nothing wrong. But if you want to integrate more than one bot, then you can lose more time. 
Thank you for your answer :)